# nftables alternative command like iptables -L -n -v

Tags: nftables

there is an alternative for command

> iptables -L -n -v

in nftables ??   I need the counter of packages that tomb on my firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nftables does not automatically create counters for rules, but if you have a rule with a counter then they can be displayed with `nft list ruleset`.

So if I have a ruleset like this.

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        ...
        # icmp
        ip protocol icmp   counter accept
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 counter accept
    }
}
```

I get the output of `nft list ruleset` that looks liek this.

```
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        ...
        ip protocol icmp counter packets 22040 bytes 781548 accept
        ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp counter packets 67 bytes 4824 accept
    }
}
```

Comment: but it count all from run  firewall yes ??   And not from "now"  like "watch iptables  -L etc... "

Comment: The counters are from the time that the rule set is activated.

Comment: oh.. so its not what I need.. domage. But thank you for your response

Comment: If you are looking for changes perhaps try something like this?  `watch -d -n 5 'nft list ruleset | grep counter'`  Adjusting the `-n 5` to an interval size that is interesting to you?